# How to create a callable method with multiple dots in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

So, I have methods like this

```
class Toast{
   static message1(){
      print('Can you')
   }

   static message2(){
      print('Help me')
   }
}
```

then I want to call it like this

```
Toast.message1()..message2();
```

Comment: You can't use [cascade notation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#cascade-notation)  to access static methods, only instance methods. If you changed the methods to instance methods you could use a syntax like `Toast()..message1()..message2();`.

Comment: Cascade notation works by evaluating to the object receiving the method call.  When you invoke a static method, there is no receiver; `static` methods are equivalent to freestanding (top-level) functions but with a different scope.